# Spfx Extension Move document

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, pnp-js-core

Hi i am trying below code to move document from Documents library to SiteAssets library , but how to make it dynamic so selected document will be move to destination library

```
  @override
  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    const destinationUrl = `/sites/test/SiteAssets/new-file.docx`;
    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'COMMAND_1':
        
     sp.web.getFileByServerRelativePath("/sites/test/Documents/test.docx").moveTo(destinationUrl);

        break;
      case 'COMMAND_2':
       // Dialog.alert(`${this.properties.sampleTextTwo}`);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown command');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the selected items in library. You can obtain those by using `event.selectedRows`.  The code should look like below

```
@override
public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
  switch (event.commandId) {
      case 'COMMAND_1':
          // Check if the user selected some items
          if (event.selectedRows.length > 0) {
              // Check the selected rows
              event.selectedRows.forEach((row: RowAccessor, index: number) => {
                  //Add the code to move files
              });
          }
          break;
      default:
          throw new Error('Unknown command');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks when i am add the code to move files it only take first selection not other ones

Comment: did you check the count of even.selectedRows? this code works in my solution

Answer (score 0):

You could get selected item id/FileRef in event.

This a screen shot of event:
[image]

Comment: thanks i am able to construct url from Fileref   "const docRelativeUrl :string = event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FileRef');" i want to construct destination url so it take same file name

Comment: i am unable to set destination url so it always take same filename from docRelativeUrl

Comment: If I select a file not a folder,the FileRef will contain file name.And in FileLeafRef attribute is the name of file.You could use these attributes to create destinationUrl.